# Redshift timestamp conversion that retains millisecond percision

Tags: timestamp, amazon-redshift

Trying to convert a bigint `1549757162511` to `timestamp` in redshift.

1. `select 1549757162511::timestamp;`

fails with `cannot cast type bigint to timestamp without time zone`

2. `select timestamp 'epoch' + 1549757162511 / 1000 * interval '1 second';`

`2019-02-10 00:06:02.000000` does not have milliseconds

3. This works...but is there a better way to do it?

`select dateadd(milliseconds, 1549757162511 % 1000, (timestamp 'epoch' + 1549757162511 / 1000 * interval '1 second'));`

`2019-02-10 00:06:02.511000`

timezone is `UTC`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found another way to do it. Not sure if it's better but it's def. cleaner.

`(timestamp 'epoch' + 1549757162511::numeric / 1000 * interval '1 second')`

Comment: This didn't work for me. Alternatively you can try
`(timestamp 'epoch' + 1549757162511::FLOAT / 1000 * interval '1 second')`

Answer (score 1):

This one also works:

`(timestamp 'epoch' + 1549757162511 * interval '0.001 seconds')`

Answer (score 0):

Here is a function you can add to simplify converting milliseconds-since-epoch to timestamps in redshift

definition

```sql
/**
 * cast milliseconds-since-epoch to timestamp
 */
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION cast_mse_to_timestamp(mse numeric)
    RETURNS timestamp
    STABLE
    AS $$
        select TIMESTAMP 'epoch' + $1 * INTERVAL '0.001 second'
    $$ LANGUAGE sql;
```

usage

```sql
select cast_mse_to_timestamp(1689469854925) // 2023-07-16 01:10:54.925000
```